# Clarification on Wikipedia's entry on Variational Bayesian methods

Tags: bayesian

**Edit: Should I post this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead?**

On the Wikipedia page for [Variational Bayesian methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_methods), it is stated that

> In variational inference, the posterior distribution over a set of
> unobserved variables $Z = \{Z_{1}\dots Z_{n}\}$ given some data
> $X$  is approximated by a
> so-called variational distribution, $Q(Z)$: $P(Z|X) \approx Q(Z)$

Here the variational distribution $Q(Z)$ is just a distribution for $Z$, not a conditional distribution of $Z|X$. However, later in the entry we have expressions such as

$$ Q(Z) = \prod_{i=1}^M q_i(Z_i|X)$$

Since

$$ q_j^*(Z_j|X) \propto E_{i \neq j} \log P(Z,X)$$

and the expectation is taken with respect to all other variables in $Z$ but $Z_j$ but not with respect to the data, I understand that $q_j^*$ should be the a conditional distribution (on the data). However, the notation $Q(Z)$ and not $Q(Z|X)$ is widespread.

Adding to my confusion is e.g. [Blei et al. (2017)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.00670.pdf) who explicitly write $q_j(z_j)$ (see e.g. equation 15) and note

> We emphasize that the variational family is not a model of the observed data—indeed, the
> data x does not appear in Equation (15)

Thoughts on this? My own understanding is that contrary to posterior distributions, which are distributions for $Z|X$, variational distributions are only functions of $Z$. Is the conditioning in the Wikipedia page used to suggest that different data $X$ would result in different approximations $Q(Z)$, even though such approximations are not conditional distributions themselves?